# React Native | title prop button must be string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html) in my react native project and running in `iOS` simulator.

While clicking on `Buttton` I'm navigating to signup page. When I click I 'm getting below errors.

**`title prop button must be string`**

CODE:

```
<View style={styles.middle}>
 <Animatable.View
  animation="fadeInUpBig"
> 
<Text style={styles.textContainer}>Welcome!</Text>

<View style={styles.formArea}>
  <TextInput
    left={<TextInput.Icon name="account-hard-hat" />} ƒ
    style={styles.FormControl}
    mode="outlined"
    label="Username"
    theme={{ colors: { primary: "#007fff" } }}
    value=""
  />
  <TextInput
    left={<TextInput.Icon name="lock" />}
    right={<TextInput.Icon name="eye-off" />}
    style={styles.FormControl}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    mode="outlined"
    label="Password"
    theme={{ colors: { primary: "#007fff" } }}
    value=""
  />
   <Text style={styles.ForgotPwd}> Forgot Password? </Text>
  <Button  style={[styles.Button]} mode="contained">
    <Text style={styles.ButtonText}> Sign In </Text>
  </Button>
  <Divider style={{ marginTop: 25, marginBottom: 25, backgroundColor: "#C6C6C6" }} />
  <Text style={styles.NewAccTxt}> Don't have an account?</Text>
  <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')} style={styles.Button} mode="contained">
<Text style={styles.ButtonText}> Create new one </Text>
  </Button>
</View>
</Animatable.View>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done this

```
<Button  style={[styles.Button]} mode="contained">
    <Text style={styles.ButtonText}> Sign In </Text>
  </Button>
```

Which wont work because React Native expects something like this

```
  <Button title={styles.ButtonText} style={[styles.Button]} />
```

Better use something like the TouchableOpacity but for button title is a required prop

Comment: `<Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')} title="Press Me" style={[styles.Button]} />` I tried like this but not working.

Comment: did you change all button instances ?

Comment: I commented all button but it did not work. getting same error

Comment: If you are getting the same error, you should have the button somewhere

Comment: Yes. I was having button in signuppage

Comment: Did it work as expected after removing or changing it ?